# Output of a code sample

Tags: c

```
int main(){
    int a = 330;
    char *p;
    p = (char *) &a;
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}
```

How is this 74 ? Plz explain?

http://codepad.org/TVeJhU1w

Comment: Why do you think it would not be 74? Did you understand the code? If not, did you read a book or tutorial explaining it? If not, why not?

Comment: What did you expect it to be then?

Comment: [This link will give you parfect answer](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/pointer-arithmatics-pre-requisites/)

Comment: It doesn't fit so you're seeing the first 8 bits of 330, which happens to be 74.

Comment: This question already has an answer here:

    What happens if you pass an int to a byte parameter in C? 7 answers

--> I dissaggree with that guys. It is quiet different what happens by letting a byte pointer point to an int or assigning an int value to a byte Var!

Answer (score 2):

If an integer is 4 bytes, there are 4 char's in it. Try to understand the output of this code:

```
int main() {
    int a =330, i;
    char *p; 

    printf("%08x\n", a); 
    p=(char *)&a;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf("%02x ", p[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(int); i++) {
        printf("%02d ", p[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

*prints:*

```
0000014a
4a 01 00 00 
74 01 00 00
```

Comment: And now continue to explain little and big endian ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using a character pointer to point to a integer variable.
Since character is just a single byte you are getting 74 .
If you had used a integer pointer then you would have got 330.

```
330 in binary is : 0000 0001 0100 1010
```

The value you are seeing here is

```
74 : 0100 1010(1byte)
```